Sum and product of 4 positive consecutive terms of some geometric progressions are 126 and 1296 respectively. Sum of ratios of all such progressions?
Exercise: if the sum and product of four positive consecutive terms of a geometric progression are $126$ and $1296$, respectively, then what is the sum of common ratios of all such geometric progressions?
My attempt: I assumed the terms to be $a/r^3$, $a/r$ , $ar$ , $ar^3$. Hence $a= 6$ or $a=-6$. Then I made the equation for sum of terms. When $a=6$, it is $r^6+r^4-21r^3+r^2+1=0$ and when $a=-6$ it is $r^6+r^4+21r^3+r^2+1=0$. Now by applying Vieta's theorem, the sum of all $r$ values is $0$ for both equations. But answer is not $0$.
Questions:

Where and why am I wrong?
How would you solve it and what will be your thought process while solving this question?
Did this question have any clicking ideas?


Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

You should not transform to the polynomial form, stay in the symmetric form. Then
$$
r^3+r+r^{-1}+r^{-3}=21
$$
can be transformed into a cubic equation for $t=r+r^{-1}$,
$$
21 = (r^2+1)(r+r^{-3})=(r+r^{-1})(r^2+r^{-2})=t(t^2-2)
\\
= u^3+v^3+(3uv-2)(u+v).
$$
The last step is for Cardano, which continues with arbitrarily but purposefully separating $3uv=2$, $u^3+v^3=21$, eliminate $v$, solve the quadratic equation, find the cubic root, reconstruct $t$, reconstruct $r$,...
Or look at the factorizations and guess $t=3$ as one of the solutions.

Your mistake was in focusing on "the sum of all $r$ values" for both equations. The question is instead about the sum of all $r^2$ values, for positive roots $r$ of both equations.
Now, using @LutzLehmann's method, you will easily conclude that the real roots of the first one are the roots of
$r^2-3r+1$, which are positive, and those of second one are their opposite (hence negative). The answer is therefore
$$\sum_{r^2-3r+1=0}r^2=\sum_{r^2-3r+1=0}(3r-1)=3\left(\sum_{r^2-3r+1=0}r\right)-2=7.$$
Note that you could discard a priori the second equation, since we want  the four terms positive and $r>0$, hence $a>0$. You could also foresee that if $r>0$ is a solution then so is $1/r$ (by reversing the order of the terms in the progression). Finally, up to this reversing, there is only one such progression.
